# Compiling in Matlab - ERROR

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors

I have used deploytool command to compile my Matlab function to an app. But I still get the same error as in the picture.[image]

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggests? Ensure that you have the correct permissions?

Comment: I don't know how to do the suggestion.

Comment: @john.steak. Then ask another question, and be sure to explain why you want to do it in the new question too.